# Masonry grid positioning

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm trying to build a masonry grid for my blog posts section and I almost got it right with some issues..
I'm not even sure if the masonry is working or the effect that I got is just because of the bootstrap columns.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What I'm trying to build is that masonry style where the posts are close to eachother and not with with that gap between them.
I used bootstrap for the posts and I'm thinking that it might be the issue. (maybe because the posts are on rows?)

Here's the html I used:

```
      <!-- start blog-posts -->
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post1 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Travelling</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Travel Best Adventure</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod tehampor
                incididunt uts laboasre et dolhvaliqua. Ut enim  vem, nostrasuaations ullamco
                labiosi ut saaliquip exoi asea comoodo Disco choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post1 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post2 -->
          <div class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/travel.jpg" alt="Post Image">
            <div class="icon-bg-pic"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Travelling</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Standard Image Post</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post2 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post3 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Fashion</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Simple Post Style</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 02, 2016</h6>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod
                tehampor choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post3 -->

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post4 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="single-img-container">
              <div class="img-fluid center-block single-img"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post4 -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post5 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="single-img2-container">
              <div class="img-fluid center-block single-img2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post5 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post6 -->
          <div class="card quote-post">
            <div class="quote-icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod tehampor
                incididunt uts laboasre et dolhvaliqua. Ut enim  vem, nostrasuaations ullamco
                labiosi ut saaliquip exoi asea comoodo Disco choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <p class="quote-name">Nathalia Alexy</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post6 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post7 -->
          <div class="card">
           <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/mountain-photo.jpg" alt="Post Image">
            <div class="icon-bg-pic"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Travelling</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Standard Image Post</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post7 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post8 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Lifestyle</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Without Image Post</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod tehampor
                incididunt uts laboasre et dolhvaliqua. Ut enim  vem, nostrasuaations ullamco
                labiosi ut saaliquip exoi asea comoodo Disco choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post8 -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post9 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Travelling</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Travel Best Adventure</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod tehampor
                incididunt uts laboasre et dolhvaliqua. Ut enim  vem, nostrasuaations ullamco
                labiosi ut saaliquip exoi asea comoodo Disco choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post9 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post10 -->
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/alone.jpg" alt="Post Image">
            <div class="icon-bg-video"><i class="fa fa-file-video-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Travelling</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Travel Best Adventure</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">January 25, 2016</h6>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum doloirs sit amet, csatetur adipisicin, sed does eiusmod tehampor
                incididunt uts laboasre et dolhvaliqua. Ut enim  vem, nostrasuaations ullamco
                labiosi ut saaliquip exoi asea comoodo Disco choice is the have great work.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary more-btn">Read More</a>
              <hr>
              <div class="card-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="comments">
                      <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      <p class="comm-nr">No Comment</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="social-share">
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post10 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post11 -->
          <div class="card link-post">
            <div class="icon-bg link-post-bg"><i class="fa fa-link fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">https://www.facebook.com/</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card link-post">
            <div class="icon-bg link-post-bg"><i class="fa fa-windows fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">https://www.facebook.com/</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post11 -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="grid-item">
          <!-- post12 -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-music fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h6 class="post-category">Audio Music</h6>
              <h4 class="card-title">Best Audio Player Post</h4>
              <h6 class="post-date">December 25, 2016</h6>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary circle-btn"><i id="play-btn" class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end post12 -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end blog-posts -->
```

Comment: Have you read up on the docs regarding Masonry and Bootstrap? Without seeing your Masonry config file, I suggest you look into these links? http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html and https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vLLeJM. Focus on the gutter-size param and bootstrap's padding. Also - masonry is NOT working in your example, as there should not be spaces BELOW the posts.

Comment: You need to post your code. Just the html is not enough information. Please provide a link or a jsfiddle as well.